# How to defend against brute-force form submissions

Tags: web-application

*(To be clear, in this question I'm not asking about how to protect a login form against brute-force attacks.)*

I work for a company which designs and builds microsites for competitions that appear on consumer products. If you've ever bought a packet of crisps which has prompted you to look for a unique code printed inside the pack and enter it on a website, then you can imagine the sort of site I mean.

The codes are usually supplied to us by our clients, and with few exceptions comprise 8 uppercase alphanumeric characters.

The website asks for a unique code, the user’s name and email address, and requires that they tick an "I agree to the terms & conditions" checkbox. A successful entrant will usually be told instantly if they have won a prize.

Typically we use reCAPTCHA (the tick box variant) to mitigate against bulk form submissions, but I worry that this is insufficient to prevent a determined attacker from flooding the site with thousands or even millions of codes they have generated.

What other steps I should be taking to ensure the security of these websites? Would a DDoS protection service (such as those offered by AWS and Google Cloud) be a good fit?

Comment: How do you do better at catching bots than one of the industry leaders at catching bots?  --  Honestly, have a conversation with Google's team.  They might be able to tailor their system specifically for your system, or at least find a way to assure you of their work (or at least get lawyers involved, so that your lawyers and their can write contracts defining who is financially responsible if bots are able to undermine entries).

Comment: @Ghedipunk while true, it's also worth pointing out that not only can Captchas be defeated, but in general such a system cannot protect against automated submissions.  See for instance: https://2captcha.com/  What you *can* do is make it so that the cost of breaking captchas is more than the gain, and come up with additional detection methods to attempt to block bots.

Comment: If you are an industry leader and this is your core competency, you could try rolling out some form of [video captcha](https://ai.google/research/pubs/pub35117/). You could even monetize it (the video could be a short ad that the user is forced to watch to win). But if this is not the central mission of your business, you are better off outsourcing to AWS or Google.